# Two DirSync in a forest

Tags: active-directory, synchronization, microsoft-office-365

I'm wondering if it is possible to have two directory synchronization tools (so, two servers) to synchronize the same AD (in my case, master of the forest), just in case of one fails or crashes ?

If the two ADFS servers situation works also with DS ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only have one Dirsync server. You cant have more than one. For ADFS, you should be deploying a farm and load balance it.

Comment: You can mitigate the risk some what by hosting the database on a separate clustered SQL instead of the dirsync server's SQL Express. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj159544. Then a backup and restore of Dirsync server in case it fails might be a good idea. Separating SQL and Dirsync means dirsync server just runs a scheduled sync periodically every 3 hours. Thats its only role. All the content can be hosted on a reliable SQL cluster for high availability.